# Como criar uma box a partir de um servidor?

Tags: servidor, vagrant

Aqui onde trabalho, estamos enfrentando muitos problemas devido a diferenças de versões de software e de ambiente de desenvolvimento. Vagrant parece ser uma ótima solução nestes casos. O problema é que nós não podemos simplesmente criar uma box vazia e ir configurando manualmente todo o SO, bibliotecas, softwares, etc. Alguém sabe me dizer se existe uma forma de criar uma espécie de imagen do servidor e usar como uma box no vagrant?

Comment: O processo varia de SO para SO, mas vendo como se faz para um talvez ajude a fazer para outro. [Aqui tem instruções para se criar um box SuSE](https://github.com/fnichol/wiki-notes/wiki/Creating-A-SLES-11.1-x64-Vagrant-Box). Vendo quais passos precisa executar (instalar o SO numa máquina virtual, instalar pacotes X e Y, etc) e adaptando-os ao seu SO particular você deve ser capaz de criar uma *base box*. P.S. Se você não quer criar um *base box*, mas sim partir de um box já existente e só configurar os pacotes, talvez o comando [`repackage`](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/box.html) te ajude

Comment: Qual serviço você está usando? AWS? DO?

Comment: Valeu cara. Vou ler aqui o link e pesquisar mais.

Comment: @PedroVinícius Gostaria de dar mais informações, mas sou bem iniciante no Vagrant. O ponto que eu queria passar é que, se você possui uma imagem do servidor que pode ser instalada em uma máquina virtual, você pode fazer isso e então terminar de configurar o que falta (i.e. instalar o Ruby, Puppet, Chef, criar um usuário `vagrant`, permitir `sudo` sem uma senha, etc) de modo a transformá-la num box. Pelo menos, foi dessa forma que eu entendi.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti, utilizamos DO aqui...

Comment: Veja se esse artigo da própria Digital Ocean te ajuda: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-digitalocean-as-your-provider-in-vagrant-on-an-ubuntu-12-10-vps